# How to get substrings from a string

Tags: .net

for example

string test = "extract substring from a string"; // extract this in to

extract

substring

from

a

string

in .net2 thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test.Split(" \t\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
string t = string.join("\n", test.split(" "));
```

Comment: Neat. It is two line feeds between each word though, not one.

Answer (score 0):

The substring function has 2 overloads as follows:

1. Substring(int startIndex)
2. Substring(int startIndex, int length)

1st type of Substring overloaded function accepts only single parameter as integer type starting index of the character position in the specified string. 2nd type Substring overloaded function accepts two types of parameters, first as integer type starting index of the character position in the string and second parameter as the integer type length or the number of characters to be returned as the substring of specified string.